# Reset content of JTable dynamically; set column headers once

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my java code, I use a `JTable`. It's not to be edited, it shows some content.

I have to:

- set column headers once
- set content dynamically

By now, I have this:

```
public class MyClass {
 final JTable table;

 public MyClass(List<List> changingContent, String[] columnHeaders) {
  table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel());
  initTable(columnHeaders); //only done once
  redrawTable(changingContent); //happens always when content changed
 }

 public void initTable(String[] columnHeaders) {
  //???? 1)
 }

 public void redrawTable(List<List> content) {
  int index = 0;
    for(Object o:content) {
        String[] rowData = presentAsStringArray(o);

        for(int i=0; i<rowData.length; i++) {
            int row = index;
            int column = i;

            //this produces an error since the rows don't exist yet
            table.getModel().setValueAt(rowData[i], row, column);
        }
        index++;
    }
 }
}
```

---

### I tried to:

1. use the `DefaultTableModel`-constructor `DefaultTableModel (String[] columnHeaders, int rows). It went bad because I don't know the number of rows at this point (and I can't know, because this can change.)
2. An idea: `setTableModel(new TableModel(data, columnHeaders)` at any redraw. But I wonder if this is not the most inefficient way of solving this.

---

### Errors I got:

- **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** from the following line which I tried to use to set the columns headers: `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(index).setValue(columnHeaders[index]);` **My guess:** the `TableColumn` already has to exist to make `getColumn(index)` work.
- **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** from resetting content (look for current code) when using following way of instantiate the `JTable`: `new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnHeaders, 0);` (`0` means the numbers of rows. I thought this could work since I am going to rewrite them.) **My guess:** Rows already have to exist.

---

### TL;DR

1. I get the column headers for the `JTable` when creating MyClass.
2. I know the Model for the tables data, but it's changing dynamically.
3. The method `redrawTable` will be run at any change.
4. I found a way that should be able to redraw cells. Unfortunately, the number of rows depends.
5. Final guess: I'm quite sure it would work to reset the TableModel at any redraw. But it doesn't seem quite efficient to me. **So why (not) doing this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use the DefaultTableModel-constructor `DefaultTableModel (String[] columnHeaders, int rows). It went bad because I don't know the number of rows at this point (and I can't know, because this can change.)

That is the correct approach. You just set the rows to 0. This would only be done when you create the table/model the first time.

> set content dynamically

Then you can clear all the data by using setRowCount(0);

Then you dynamically add rows using the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel.

So your basic logic would be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);

for(Object o:content) 
{
    String[] rowData = presentAsStringArray(o);
    model.addRow( rowData );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I correct undertand you. When you need to change the number of rows, you simply need to use the method `DefaultTableModel.setRowCount(int)`. Something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
     final JTable table;
     final DefaultTableModel model;

     public MyClass(List<List> changingContent, String[] columnHeaders) {
          model = new DefaultTableModel(columnHeaders, 0); // init model with 0 rows
          table = new JTable(model);
          redrawTable(changingContent); //happens always when content changed
     }


     public void redrawTable(List<List> content) {
        model.setRowCount(content.size()); // set the correct row count here
        int index = 0;
        for(Object o:content) {
            String[] rowData = presentAsStringArray(o);

            for(int i=0; i<rowData.length; i++) {
                int row = index;
                int column = i;

                //this produces an error since the rows don't exist yet
                model.setValueAt(rowData[i], row, column);
            }
            index++;
        }
     }
}
```